# Notify opportunity owner of a newly deactivated Service

Tags: apex, email, custom-button

I have created a custom button that deletes the pricebook entry and makes a product inactive when clicked. For products that have never been used in an opportunity this works great as the product is no longer available for account managers in an opportunity.

For products that have previously been used in opportunities the button doesn't work and fires an error to the user saying the product is attached to an opportunity - this is fine as it's probably important we can report on historic opportunities.

What would be AMAZING, is if we could fire an email alert to the opportunity owner, explaining that the product should no longer be used in the open opportunity. The question is, how would we do this? Because I only know the pricebook entry can't be deleted because the apex class fails, and I get a notification the process builder flow hasn't been able to run.

Answer (score 0):

One way i could think of creating a batch job and doing a one time run for existing records for which product is inactive.You can send emails using the batch job.